# "vagrant up" succeeds but "vagrant ssh" fails with "VM must be running to open SSH connection"

Tags: linux, jenkins, vagrant, virtualbox

On a Fedora Linux 3.6.11 system I'm using Jenkins to concurrently run two jobs that use the same script to test a software package on two different VMs. One of the jobs routinely fails because Vagrant can't ssh(1) to the VM that it just created.

The script contains this:

```
set -e
$vmName=...
( flock 9; vagrant up $vmName # attempt to prevent concurrent "vagrant up"
) 9>/tmp/`basename $0`-$USER
trap "vagrant destroy --force $vmName; `trap -p EXIT`" EXIT

# Execute test commands on the virtual machine:
vagrant ssh $vmName -- -T <<EOF
    ...
EOF
```

Here's the failure output (with some elision):

```
+ flock 9
+ vagrant up centos64_64
Bringing machine 'centos64_64' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> centos64_64: Importing base box 'centos-6.4-x86_64-devel'...

 [KProgress: 10%
 ...
 [K==> centos64_64: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> centos64_64: Setting the name of the VM: delivery_centos64_64_1425494409930_40170
==> centos64_64: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> centos64_64: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> centos64_64: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    centos64_64: Adapter 1: nat
==> centos64_64: Forwarding ports...
    centos64_64: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
==> centos64_64: Booting VM...
==> centos64_64: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    centos64_64: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    centos64_64: SSH username: vagrant
    centos64_64: SSH auth method: private key
    centos64_64: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    centos64_64: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    centos64_64: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> centos64_64: Machine booted and ready!
==> centos64_64: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> centos64_64: Mounting shared folders...
    centos64_64: /vagrant = <http://spock:8080/jenkins/job/LDM_Acceptance_64 bit_CentOS_6.4/ws/archive/delivery>
centos64_64: /tmp/vagrant-puppet-2/manifests => <http://spock:8080/jenkins/job/LDM_Acceptance_64-bit_CentOS_6.4/ws/archive/delivery/puppet>
==> centos64_64: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> centos64_64: Running Puppet with centos-devel.pp...
==> centos64_64: Notice: Compiled catalog for centos6464.unidata.ucar.edu in environment production in 1.30 seconds
++ trap -p EXIT
+ trap 'vagrant destroy --force centos64_64; ' EXIT
+ vagrant ssh centos64_64 -- -T
VM must be running to open SSH connection. Run `vagrant up`
to start the virtual machine.
+ vagrant destroy --force centos64_64
==> centos64_64: Destroying VM and associated drives...
==> centos64_64: Running cleanup tasks for 'puppet' provisioner...
```

Both VMs are NATed. The successful job's VM got port 2222 for ssh(1) while the failed job's VM (above) got port 2200. Each job has its own directory and copy of the Vagrantfile.

Any advice on how to ensure that both `vagrant ssh`-s succeed would be appreciated.